# Why is the compiler rejecting my execv function call?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, execv

I am trying to execute the `cp` command with two options `--preserve` and `--interactive`

And in my code I have:

```
char const *copy[] = {"/bin/cp","cp","-p","-i",0};

execv(copy[0],copy);
```

But it is giving me this error

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const char**' to 'char* const*'   
error: initializing argument 2 of 'int execv(const char*, char* const*)'
```

What should I change for this to work?

Comment: Just remove `const` from the first line.

Comment: @zgyarmati: the presence of C++ in the title of your proposed duplicate makes it somewhat inappropriate for a question tagged C.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should declare copy as:

```
char *const copy[] = {"/bin/cp", "cp", "-p", "-i", 0};
```

See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html